# Expansion of Expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to expand out expressions that have several terms similar to

```
E[-lH] Sinh[l (H - h)]
```

The `Expand` command just gives me back the original expression. Even when I do a partial expansion, and then try `Expand`:

```
Expand[E[-l H] (E[l (H - h)] - E[-l (H - h)])]
```

I get back:

```
E[-H l] (-E[(h - H) l] + E[(-h + H) l])
```

From `ExpandAll`:

```
-E[-H l] E[h l - H l] + E[-H l] E[-h l + H l]
```

I would like `E[-lH] Sinh[l (H - h)]` to be expanded as:

```
E[-h l] - E[(h - 2 H)l]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`E` is a constant, so either use it as `E^(-H l))` or use `Exp[-H l]`.
Then you can do :

```
Simplify[TrigToExp[Exp[-l H] Sinh[l (H - h)]]]
(* 1/2 (E^(-h l) - E^((h - 2 H) l)) *)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did answer the question I asked. But when I tried: Simplify[TrigToExp[Exp[-l H] Sinh[l (H - h)] Sinh[l x]]], I get:    1/4 E^(l (h - 2 H - x)) (-1 + E^(2 (-h + H) l)) (-1 + E^(2 l x)). Is there a way to have this completely expanded out?

Comment: I get the fully expanded result with ExpandAll: ExpandAll[TrigToExp[Exp[-l H] Sinh[l (H - h)] Sinh[l x]]] gives: -(1/4) E^(-h l - l x) + 1/4 E^(h l - 2 H l - l x) +  1/4 E^(-h l + l x) - 1/4 E^(h l - 2 H l + l x)

Comment: Just use `Expand[...]` or equivalently `... //Expand`.